# Nhibernate Datetime issues

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate

i'm currently experiencing a little problem. I'm using nhibernate with around 40 entities mapped to a sql server database. however, due to performance reasons some operations are done via stored procedure. 
i have a stored procedure that takes 3 parameters. one entity ID and 2 DateTime's.

now, when i have a Date like the 10th of Dezember 2008, Nhibernate makes

```
'10.12.2008 00:00:00.000'
```

out of it. (German Culture)
But Sql Server 2008 doesn't interpret it correctly as it swaps Day and Month.
When i manually change the datetime text to

```
'2008-12-10 00:00:00.000'
```

i didn't encounter this problem when using the session in a "normal" way or when using NHibernate.linq. just when using a sql-query to execute the stored procedure.

is there a way to manually overcome the way NHibernate transforms DateTime objects to their textual representation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHibernate shouldn't be transforming DateTimes into their textual representation at all, IMO - it should be asking the database driver to pass that DateTime along in whatever form it wants to.

Is your stored procedure declared to receive the parameter *as* DateTimes (or whatever the SQL type is) or varchar? If if's declared as receiving a DateTime and NHibernate knows that, then it *should* just be using parameterised call as normal.

Answer (score 1):

i pass the datetimes with .SetDateTime(name,datetimeValue) to the IQuery, therefore i thought nhibernate should take care of it. the stored procedure expects DateTime parameters.
i just saw this textual representation when i turned show_sql on

Comment: Turn profiling on at the server, to see what's actually coming across. I wouldn't be surprised if show_sql was just using the current culture to display the parameter - that doesn't mean the text is necessarily coming across that way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same thing with a single DateTime in a being passed into a CLR stored proc.  Mine is also multiple parameters. I've tried it as a string, as well, and i get errors no matter what I do.  Here's the code from the mapping file:

"
      
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
      
      exec spGetRentRollByDate :@propertyID :@reportDate
    "

The stored proc first looks for a resultset in a given table, and if it's not there, it cfires off another function to create one and returns that set instead.